# Tensor product with an algebra bimodule

Tags: modules, representation-theory, tensor-products, algebras

I am having a little difficulty in understanding the module structure of tensor products of modules over algebras (as opposed to arbitrary rings). To help me understand, here is an example.

Let $K[x]$ be the polynomial algebra in one variable over an algebraically closed field $K$. Let $A$ be a $K$-algebra. Suppose $M$ is a $K[x]$-$A$-bimodule such that $M$ is finitely generated and free as a left $K[x]$-module. (By free, we mean that $M$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $K[x]$, where the algebra is considered as a left module over itself.) Let $S$ be a simple right $K[x]$-module.

Consider the module $S \otimes_{K[x]} M$. This is a right $A$-module.

How does one determine the underlying K-vectorspace of $S \otimes_{K[x]} M$? Supposedly, this module is finite-dimensional, although this confuses me, since I thought the dimension was multiplicative over a tensor product (and $K[x]$ is an infinite-dimensional algebra). Why?

Finally, what is the right action of an element $a \in A$ on $S \otimes_{K[x]} M$?

Comment: If $M$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $K\left[x\right]$, then $S \otimes_{K\left[x\right]} M$ will be isomorphic to a corresponding direct sum of copies of $S \otimes_{K\left[x\right]} K\left[x\right] \cong S$ (since tensor products commute with direct sums). Do you know a basis of $S$ ?

Comment: Any simple $K[x]$-module $S$ is a one-dimensional vector space with right action $sx=\lambda s$ for any $s \in S$ and some $\lambda \in K$ ($K[x]$ has infinitely many simple modules, indexed by $K$). Thus, any element of $K$ will suffice as a basis. What about the right $A$-action on $S \otimes_{K[x]} M$? How does this relate to the right action on $M$? Or are more specifics required to answer that question?

Comment: The right $A$-action on $S \otimes_{K\left[x\right]} M$ is defined in terms of that on $M$ (namely, $\left(s \otimes m\right) a = s \otimes \left(ma\right)$ for all $s \in S$, $m \in M$ and $a \in A$). So, yes, we need to know the latter to tell anything about the former.